# Is there any synchronization regarding lifecycle methods of two sibling React components, which are conditionally rendered?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose that in a react component, two siblings are rendered conditionally, meaning that one will get unmounted when the other gets rendered. In this scenario, is it guaranteed that **componentDidMount** method of the rendered component gets executed before other’s **componentWillUnmount**?

Comment: Show an example.

Comment: Seems like its in sync, here's my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dmb82g